# Nasb 2020 implying creation not in 7 days?

Tags: genesis, creation, nasb

My nasb 2020 says God did ... on A 2nd day, A 3rd day, etc. rather than on THE 2nd day, THE 3rd day, etc. Is it implying the days were not consecutive? That day 4 may have been a few thousand years after day 3? If so, does this contradict the Hebrew? Or can the Hebrew be interpreted both ways?

Answer (score 4):

The Hebrew here is pretty interesting and poses awkwardness for English translation:

וַיְהִי עֶרֶב וַיְהִי בֹקֶר יוֹם **אֶחָד**

wayəhî-ʿereḇ wayəhî-ḇōqer **yôm ʾeḥāḏ**

Literally translated, this means:

and evening was, and morning was, **day one.** (Genesis 1.5b)

Point being it is a [cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_numerals) "one", not an ordinal "first". If an ordinal was meant, the text would say "rishon" (first), and not "echad" (one).

But for the rest of the days, we have only *ordinal* numbers:

- verse 1.8: וַיְהִי עֶרֶב וַיְהִי בֹקֶר יוֹם **שֵׁנִי** - wayəhî-ʿereḇ wayəhî-ḇōqer yôm **šēnî** - "and it was evening, and it was morning, second day". **šēnî** is the ordinal "second"

All the other numbers are also ordinal:

- verse 1.13: wayəhî-ʿereḇ wayəhî-ḇōqer yôm **šəlîšî** - "And it was evening, and it was morning, *third day*"
- verse 1.19: "wayəhî-ʿereḇ wayəhî-ḇōqer yôm **rəḇîʿî**" - "And it was evening, and it was morning, *fourth day*"
- verse 1.23: "wayəhî-ʿereḇ wayəhî-ḇōqer yôm **ḥămîšî**" - "And it was evening, and it was morning, *fifth* day"
- verse 1.31: "wayəhî-ʿereḇ wayəhî-ḇōqer yôm **haššiššî**" - "And it was evening, and it was morning, *sixth* day"

Similarly for the seventh day in chapter 2.1-3, we also have the ordinal *seventh*, šəḇîʿî.

In none of the above is there an article.

As far as I know, no English translation carries this distinction of cardinal and ordinal numbers, as it makes for awkward English, and English translations tend to add articles, but you cannot compare English and Hebrew articles as they follow different usage conventions.

What we have from this passage, in Hebrew, is the makings of a count. E.g. the first day *starts the count*. Subsequent days are referred as the second, third, etc. *of that count*.

And that's all you're going to get from the Hebrew.

An intuitive reading is that these are six days one after the other. The text doesn't explicitly state that, but that is the clear meaning of the text. All of Genesis 1-3 is quite cryptic and very brief, and there are oceans of interpretations, from pedestrian to zany, of what this count represents.

For example, St. Augustine interpreted the "day 1" of the count as the start of time. E.g. he was one of the first to view time itself as part of creation, although I would argue that many early Christians took this view, interpreting the "last day" and "end time" as literally -- e.g. the end of time and the start of a completely new thing.

As another example, a while ago I read a book called *[Genesis and the Big Bang](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0553354132)* which tried to make [cosmological sense](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iuE21gcxONA) of Genesis, arguing that the "day 1" represents a rooting of the observer, to where matter begins, and then he continued to argue that a 24 hour period for a stationary observer at that initial point in time would correspond to billions of years for an observer on earth, as the universe was expanding and it would take longer for a light signal to reach wherever you are from that initial point. This was an attempt to use relativity theory to get an old earth creation consistent with seven 24 hour time periods.

The weakness with all these theories is that our scientific knowledge changes, so after you've succeeded in building some scaffolding linking the Genesis account to what we currently understand, in the future the ground would have shifted, and you'll need to patch up the scaffolding. So there is always an element of *motivated reasoning* whenever people struggle to make Genesis 1 into a scientific text, and for this reason the field of apologetics is not the best approach for hermeneutic study, and I am not advocating any apologetics-based interpretation of things like articles or ordinal numbers. My recommendation is to just study what the text says and put a firewall between the interpretation of the text and any apologetics exercise, so that at least the ground on one side of your scaffolding is sure and stable.

Comment: Young's Literal states, I think, what you are looking for _and there is an evening, and there is a morning -- day one._. . . . .   _and there is an evening, and there is a morning -- day second._. Up-voted +1 : very informative indeed. Appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, @NigelJ, should have guessed that YLT would get this right

Answer (score 0):

First, the purpose and grammatical function of the Hebrew article (equivalent of "the") is different from English and so the presence or absence in one language does not imply the same thing in the other.

The literary structure of Genesis 1:3-31, recounting the six days of creation is simple and compelling:

- And God said ...
- [what was done and said by God]
- And there was evening and morning, day "N" (one, two, three, etc)

In a private letter from Prof. Barr (at Oxford) to Mr David C C Watson in Illinois, dated 23 April 1984, he stated this:

> “… probably, so far as I know, there is no professor of Hebrew or Old
> Testament at any world-class university who does not believe that the
> writer(s) of Genesis 1–11 intended to convey to their readers the
> ideas that:
>
> (a)   creation took place in a series of six days which were the same as
> the days of 24 hours we now experience
>
> (b)   the figures contained in the Genesis genealogies provided by
> simple addition a chronology from the beginning of the world up to
> later stages in the biblical story
>
> (c)   Noah’s flood was understood to be world-wide and extinguish all
> human and animal life except for those in the ark.”

The days are intended to be seen as consecutive, without question.  To suggest otherwise renders the chronology meaningless.

[To suggest that the six days were separated by long eons is equivalent to a friend's experience when he asked a panting company for a quote to paint his house - "three days" was the response beginning on Monday.  When no one turned up on Tuesday the comment from the painting company was - the next day is in a month's time and third day will be in two months' time!]

Thus, I disagree with the latest NASB translation at this point.